# The mathics.net webpage always responds "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request!"

Tags: mathics

The mathics.net webpage responds "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request!" to every statement.  (I've tried with IE and Firefox on Win7, and in Chrome on Android.)  Also, I cannot create an account to Login, because the webpage never sends me e-mail.  And my e-mail to a person I found on the site (not Mr. Poeschko) was never answered.  Mathics seems very attractive, but it is frustrating not to be able to get any intelligent result from it.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Not a programming question. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company/255746#255746

Answer (score 1):

The mathics.net website it maintained by the creator of Mathics who no longer really looks after it. This also means that the instructions on mathics.org are out of date. The updated site is http://mathics.github.io/ .

There are two immediate solutions to this:

- Install Mathics locally and use it on localhost up to date [Guide here](https://github.com/mathics/Mathics/wiki/Installing).
- Try my personal mirror http://mathics.angusgriffith.com.

I'd recommend installing Mathics locally since you're free to run long queries and use all the features.

**Source/Disclaimer**: I currently maintain the Mathics project (on Github).

Comment: Wonderful!  Thanks for the website.